# Get individuals survey responses from survey monkey using API method

Tags: surveymonkey

Using the Survey Monkey API i am creating the surveys from my web application with a Web Link Collector.
I want to get the individuals response for the Survey as a Survey template Format with responded data.

Is it possible to get the each individuals response as a web link from survey monkey using Survey monkey API.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do a add recipient and then get personal links. I dont know about survey monkey but I have done this like tons of times with Examinare.

Paying alittle gets it really easily when coding according to my experience:

There is a howto for CakePHP here : https://developer.examinare.com/how-to-use-surveys-in-cakephp-with-very-little-development/